# i cannot understand "sort function"

Tags: javascript, function

this questions maybe Easy for you .. but i am new in javascript

i cannot understand this part in function

> kids.sort(function(n, m)

**what n and m ??** and  how i can understand this kind of functions

thsnks

```
<script>
function sortkids(e) {
     if (typeof e == "string") e = document.getElementById(e);
     var kids = [];
     for(var x = e.firstChild; x != null; x = x.nextSibling)
         if (x.nodeType == 1) kids.push(x);
     kids.sort(function(n, m) { 
                   var s = n.firstChild.data; 
                   var t = m.firstChild.data;
                   if (s < t) return -1;    
                   else if (s > t) return 1;  
                   else return 0;           
               });

     for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) e.appendChild(kids[i]);
}
</script>
<ul id="list"> 
<li>one<li>two<li>three<li>four <!-- items are not in alphabetical order -->
</ul>
<button onclick="sortkids('list')">Sort list</button>
```

Comment: You pass a "compare" function to "sort", which uses the compare function to compare any two items (to see which one comes first).  This is a very elementary pattern in JavaScript -- you need to get a good book on JavaScript and read through it.  Don't assume that if you know another programming language you can pick up JavaScript just by trial-and-error.

Comment: @Stephen Chung thanks i have "javascript good part" but it is Difficult for beginner

Comment: Well, try something like "JavaScript for Beginners"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.sort` is doing the actual sorting for you, i.e. the shuffling around of items inside the array. What you need to tell `.sort` is *how* you want items sorted. You do this by supplying a function that takes two parameters and returns as information which of the two you consider "bigger" or "smaller" or whether both are equal (with the return values `-1`, `0` and `1`).

`.sort` goes through the array, passing two elements at a time into your function asking *"which one is bigger?"*, sorting the array based on the answer. It does this repeatedly until the array is sorted.

Comment: thanks man .. advise me a book or an article ِabout functions

Comment: @tarek Never really read one, so can't advise. *Any* Javascript book should discuss functions though; if it doesn't, it's not a book about Javascript. Or programming for that matter. :P

Comment: hahaha You're right .. but I do not understand parameters In some cases such as this example

Answer (score 1):

`n` and `m` will be elements from the array. The function will be called repeatedly, with different array elements to compare, and is expected to return a value saying whether `n` is less than, greater than, or equal to `m`. This lets `sort` do its job of sorting the array, even though `sort` doesn't know anything about the elements. All it needs to know, it gets from the function you pass in.

What that code is doing is putting DOM elements in an array, and then sorting it, which will only sort the elements in the array, not in the DOM. So then the bit at the end, doing the `e.appendChild` calls, is taking the sorted array and moving the elements in the DOM so they're in the right place. (It works because when you call `appendChild` with an element that's already in the DOM elsewhere, it gets moved; and `appendChild` always appends at the end.)